# Shuffle matrix without the shuffle() method

Tags: python, matrix

I need to take a matrix:

```
m = [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]
```

and shuffle it, which I have been doing like this:

```
m[0][0], m[0][1], m[1][0], m[1][1] = m[1][0], m[0][0], m[1][1], m[0][1] # or some other combination
```

I don't want it to be random because I want to be able to reverse it, and while I don't mind doing the above with a 2x2 matrix I'll need to do it with 4x4's and bigger and don't feel like hard coding all those indexes.

I also don't want to just switch rows, like this: `m[0], m[1] = m[1], m[0]` but the individual values, `m[0][1]` and `m[1][0]` for example.

Comment: you want to rotate the matrix?

Comment: Can you please include the reason why you doing it, so we avoid [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: I'm making a simple encryption algorithm for fun, and am looking for a way to shuffle a matrix.

Comment: No, I have already been using that. I'm looking for a way to shuffle the individual indexes without writing them all out

Comment: Almost, but again, instead of changing the rows I want to swap individual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shuffle the "flattened" indices. By "flattened" in case of 2x2 matrix I mean index `0` is a `[0][0]`, `1` is `[0][1]`, `2` is `[1][0]`, and `3` is `[1][1]`. In general for the matrix with `c` columns, index `n` is equivalent to `[n//c][n%c]`.

The shuffled indices (numbers from `0` to `#rows * #columns`) use as indices for the new matrix. I.e. `replace_indices = [3, 1, 0, 2]` would mean that in shuffled matrix 0th index (`[0][0]`) will be taken from the 3rd index (`[1][1]`) of the original matrix. And so on:

```
from random import shuffle

m = ...

rows = len(m)
cols = len(m[0])

replace_indices = list(range(rows * cols))
shuffle(replace_indices)

shuffled_m = [[0] * cols for c in range(rows)]

for idx, sidx in enumerate(replace_indices):
    shuffled_m[idx//rows][idx%rows] = m[sidx//rows][sidx%rows]
```

now to unshuffle, you can use the same `replace_indices` but in reverse:

```
unshuffled_m = [[0] * cols for c in range(rows)]

for idx, sidx in enumerate(replace_indices):
    unshuffled_m[sidx//rows][sidx%rows] = shuffled_m[idx//rows][idx%rows]
```

In other words, `replace_indices` is a symmetric-key of your encryption.

Comment: So do you mind explaining whats going on here? thanks

Comment: Will try to clarify it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

This seemed like a fun exercise for numpy arrays. My solution is pretty verbose, but I hope it helps illustrate each step.

```
import numpy as np
import random


in_data = [[10,20,30,40],
            [51,61,71,81],
            [92,102,112,122],
            [133,143,153,163]]

array = np.array(in_data)  # Create array
print('Start array:\n', array)

old_shape = array.shape  # Preserve shape
long_array = np.reshape(array, array.size)  # turn it into a 1xN vector
print('long_array: ', long_array)


index = np.arange(0, array.size) # Create a simple 0-N index
print('index: ', index)
random.shuffle(index)  # Shuffle the index
print('shuffled index: ', index)

long_array = long_array[index]  # Apply shuffled index to the data array
print('shuffled long array: ', long_array[index])

shuffled_array = long_array.reshape(old_shape) # Create the 4x4 shape using the old_shape

print('reshaped shuffled array:\n', shuffled_array)

### UNSHUFFLING
# Generate a new linear index and sort the shuffled index to obtain a reverse sort
new = np.vstack([index, np.arange(0,len(index))])
new = new.T

unshuffled_index = new[new[:,0].argsort()].T[1,:]  # Sort the shuffled_index column
print("unshuffled_index: ", unshuffled_index)

# Condensed reshape, re-index, re-shape of the shuffled data
orig = np.reshape(np.reshape(shuffled_array, array.size)[unshuffled_index], old_shape)


print('original data:\n', orig)
```

This would be much cleaner if I could avoid the reshaping to 1xN and/or had a more clever way to reverse the shuffle.